# Tensorflow, update the Variable to have arbitrary shape

Tags: tensorflow

So, according to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable), we can use tf.assign with validate_shape=False to change the shape. It does change the shape of the content of the variable, but the shape you can get from get_shape() doesn't get updated. For example:

```
>>> a = tf.Variable([1, 1, 1, 1])
>>> sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
>>> tf.assign(a, [[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], validate_shape=False).eval()
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], dtype=int32)
>>> a.get_shape()
TensorShape([Dimension(4)])
```

It's pretty annoying that the later layers of the network base their shapes on the get_shape() value of this variable. So, even though the actual shape is correct, Tensorflow will complain the dimensions doesn't match. So any ideas on how to update the "believed" shape of each Variable?

Comment: set_shape maybe?

Comment: `set_shape` will try to validate against existing shape information. I'd set `validate_shape=False` when _creating_ the variable, in which case the static shape information will be fully unknown (and you can refine it with `set_shape` if you'd like).

Comment: I'll give it a try. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In short: use [set_shape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#set_shape) to update the static shape of the variable.

---

You can understand what is going on by reading the [TF FAQ](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/faq#tensor_shapes):

> In TensorFlow, a tensor has both a static (inferred) shape and a
>   dynamic (true) shape. The static shape can be read using the
>   `tf.Tensor.get_shape` method: this shape is inferred from the operations
>   that were used to create the tensor, and may be partially complete. If
>   the static shape is not fully defined, the dynamic shape of a Tensor t
>   can be determined by evaluating `tf.shape(t)`.

So the static shape was not properly inferred and you should give TF a hint. Luckily the next few lines from the same FAQ tell you what to do:

> The tf.Tensor.set_shape method updates the static shape of a Tensor
>   object, and it is typically used to provide additional shape
>   information when this cannot be inferred directly. It does not change
>   the dynamic shape of the tensor.

Answer (score 0):

Since `validate_shape` is set to false static shape of the variable doesn't get update automatically in the graph. a wrokaround is to set it manualy with the new shape (that's known)

```
a = tf.Variable([1, 1, 1, 1], validate_shape=False)
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
new_arr_assign = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
tf.assign(a, new_arr_assign, validate_shape=False).eval(session=sess)
a.set_shape(new_arr_assign.shape)
a.get_shape()
# results: TensorShape([Dimension(2), Dimension(7)])
```